# Enforce the type of props.children in TypeScript React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a React component that can only receive children of a specific type. More specifically, to receive children of a different React component.

The goal for this is to have intellisense when composing the children of a component.

For example, this should be fine:

```
<PlantParent name="Sammy" age={26}>
  <Plant name="Macadamia" species="cactus" ageInMonths={6} />
  <Plant name="Chocolate Cheesecake" species="succulent" ageInMonths={24} />
</PlantParent>
```

But this should give me an error or warning:

```
<PlantParent name="Sammy" age={26}>
  <Plant name="Macadamia" species="cactus" ageInMonths={6} />
  <Plant name="Chocolate Cheesecake" species="succulent" ageInMonths={24} />
  <li>sup, I am not a plant</li>
</PlantParent>
```

Because in the declaration of `PlantParent`, It should be defined that the children of `PlantParent` should be a list of `Plant` components.

I have tried approaching this by defining the type of the children of `PlantParent` in the props, like so:

```
type PlantParentProps = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  children: React.FC<PlantItem>;
};
```

But doing this fails both cases above instead of just the second, with the error:

```
Type '{ children: Element[]; name: string; age: number; }' is not assignable to type 'PlantParentProps'.
    Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
        Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<PlantItem>'.
```

Which makes sense since I am not ensuring that the children of `<PlantParent>` are of type `<Plant>`, but I am just at a loss about what next steps to take in here or how to ensure that/if the children are of a certain type.

I have an example going on in here with the code above and the implementation of Plant and Plant Parent: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-cerf-ijl4c

Thanks!

Comment: Found this which may help [react-children-composition-patterns-with-typescript](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/react-children-composition-patterns-with-typescript-56dfc8923c64)

Comment: Tried `children: Exclude<React.ReactNode, JSX.Element>` but not work